# Issues with Blogger and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I'm working on blogger and I've been trying to make a menu with some dropdowns using JQuery but for some reason it isn't working on Blogger, in my pc it works just fine. I've added the scripts and the style to the page HTML and then I placed the body on a HTML block but it doesn't work there.

[Picture from the blog structure with the HTML Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6DGW.png)

Here's the demo I'm using on my pc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
        .menu {
            padding:10px 0;
            width: 500px;
        }
        .menu ul {
            list-style-type:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .menu ul li {
            display:inline-block;
            position:relative;
        }
        .menu ul li ul {    
            background-color:rgb(225,75,75);
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:40px; /* make this equal to the line-height of the links (specified below) */
            width:200px;
        }
        .menu li li {
            position:relative;
            margin:0;
            display:block;
        }
        .menu li li ul {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:500px; /* make this equal to the width of the sub nav above */
            margin:0;
        }

        .menu a {
            line-height:40px;
            padding:0 12px;
            margin:0 12px;
        }
        .menu a {
            color:#000;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:block;
        }
        .menu a:hover,
        .menu a:focus,
        .menu a:active {
            color:rgb(255,00,00);
        }

        /* style sub level links */
        .menu li li a {
            border-bottom:solid 1px rgb(200,50,50);
            margin:0 10px;
            padding:0;
        }
        .menu li li:last-child a {
            border-bottom:none;
        }

        /* show arrows for dropdowns */
        .menu li.dropdown > a {
            background-image:url('../img/arrow-down.png');
            background-position:right 20px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }

        .menu li li.dropdown > a {
            background-image:url('../img/arrow-right.png');
            background-position:right 16px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
            /* hide sub menu links */
        ul.sub-menu {
            display:none;
        }

        </style>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('.dropdown').hover( 

                    function(){
                        $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown(200,stop()); 
                    },

                    function(){
                       $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideUp(200,stop()); 
                    }

                );

                function stop(){
                    $('.sub-menu').stop(true, true);
                }

            });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul >
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Streams</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit:
I've also trying making an alert in the JQuery function and when the mouse passed over the menu the alert appears but the dropdown doesn't.

Comment: http://mtg4everyone.blogspot.pt/ Is the blog website. Some errors are from missing arrow images that I haven't uploaded yet. I had an JQuery error but I've already fixed it, feel free to check the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question is... Blogger's gadget for HTML/Javascript block applies some css that was making the bar not show up. You can either find a way to remove the css from the gadget or simply place your HTML code on the HTML page.